# How to dynamically add component as a child of directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I want to add a tooltip component as a child of the template that a directive is applied on.

```html
<div class="wrapper"
tooltipDirective
[label]="'Sample tooltip label'">
Hover on this
</div>
```

tooltip.directive.ts

```js
import { TooltipComponent} from './tooltip.component'

@Directive({
    selector: '[tooltipDirective]',
})
export class TooltipDirective {

    @Input() label: string = '';

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private vrc: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    @HostListener('mouseenter')
    onMouseEnter() {
        console.log('mousenter');

        //doing this adds the new component as sibling not as child <--------------------
        let compRef = this.vrc.createComponent(TooltipComponent);
        compRef.setInput('show', true);
        compRef.setInput('label', this.label);
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')
    onMouseLeave() {
        this.vrc.clear();
    }
   
}
```

I just want the new tooltip component to be inserted inside the `<div class="wrapper"></div>`. Also I want to be able to destroy this component when the mouse leaves.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured a workaround. Not exactly the solution I wanted and not very elegant but it works.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
Hover on this
<ng-template
tooltipDirective
[label]="'Sample tooltip label'"
></ng-template>
</div>
```

NOTE FOR MYSELF.
This should create the new component as sibling of the  and so it will be the child of the . This does mean I won't be able detect events on the parent in the directive itself and they will have to be passed in. For now this solution is fine.

It will also allow the user to control when the tooltip is really displayed. If they want the hitbox to be a different object and the tooltip to appear around a different element they could do this easily with this approach. But it also makes it harder for the users who just want to add a tooltip as they now have to keep track of the isMouseOver themselves.